# Multiplying two fields in django models to get total value but total value not getting updated in the database

Tags: python, django, postgresql

My model looks like this. Other fields are getting updated in the database just as expected.
The problem is getting the total value stored in the database by multiplying the price_per_unit with     the quantity. Is there something I am missing ?

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models import Sum
from django.db.models import F

class CowData(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="item")
    user = models.CharField( max_length=20, null=False)
    added_on = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    feed = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    price_per_unit = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    total = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    
 
total = ( CowData.objects
        .filter()
            .aggregate(
                total=Sum('total', field="quantity*price_per_unit")
             )['total']
         )
```

Comment: Can you please add some more code on how you use the model? If you already have the `quantity` and `price_per_unit` stored in your database it probably makes more sense to make `total` a property or something. Explaining what you want to achieve and how to use the values will help us with finding a good solution.

Comment: @GlennDJ, Thanks for replying. I'll do my best to clarify. I am trying to develop a farm inventory application, diary farm is one category. I have a django form where a user should key in different values, like the ones in my model. I would like to calculate the total price based on the quantity and price_per_unit and store that in a field named total for every new entry. The rest is just a view file which renders the form page.

Comment: Ok got it, I'm going to suggest a different approach in my answer then.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment the best approach seems to be overwriting the `save` method of the model which allows the `total` value to be computed every time before saving the instance. Example:

```
class CowData(models.Model):
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    price_per_unit = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    total = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.total = self.price_per_unit * self.quanity
        super(CowData, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```